# Excel function to be use in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to use Mod function of Excel to write pinescript code. How can I use it?
The script is MOD((SQRT((9654))*180)-225,360).

Could not find MOD function in pinescript.

I have checked Math function but not found there. Should I look for another functions? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

`MOD` is `%` in pinescript. [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#arithmetic-operators) are the other arithmetic operators.

You can write the same expression as below:

```
result = ((math.sqrt(9654)*180) - 225) % 360
plotchar(result, "result", "")
```